# Counting items in a queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter, django-filters

This works

```
RoomBookings.objects.filter(HotelName__HotelName__icontains=hotel.HotelName, RoomType__icontains= hotel.RoomType).count()
```

But this doesn't work

```
queryset2 = RoomBookings.objects.filter(HotelName__HotelName__icontains=hotel.HotelName, RoomType__icontains= hotel.RoomType),
                
print(queryset2.count())
```

And I have also tried

```
print(queryset2.objects.count())
print (queryset2.objects.all().count())
print (queryset2.objects.all().len())             
print (queryset2.objects().filter().count())
print (queryset2.len())
print (queryset2.all().len())
print (queryset2.objects.len())
```

Comment: Remove the `,` at the end. Writing it like so makes it a tuple.

Comment: By adding a comma at the end, you wrapped the data into a singleton tuple.

Comment: I cannot believe a stupid comma was causing my problem! Thank you Ene and William.